# Recording Video & Audio on Windows and Showing Current Camera View

Tags: c++, qt, camera, video-capture

I was planning to use Qt to record video/audio and to show the camera view while it is recording. However, there is a bug report with recording videos on Windows, as reported in [this page](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30541?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel), and I confirmed that the issue is legitimate. There wasn't any problem with recording video and audio on Macintosh and Linux-Ubuntu.

Due to this issue with Qt, I'm looking for another C++ library that does video and audio recording and can display the camera view. It will be great if it is easy to use and integrate into my project.